# SQL TRIGGER phpMyAdmin - LEAVE instruction

Tags: php, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have this trigger in phpMyAdmin

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `DuplicateRows` BEFORE INSERT ON `infocontacts` 
FOR EACH ROW
trig : BEGIN 
DECLARE num INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

IF( NEW.phone <> 'NULL' ) THEN
 SELECT COUNT( * ) INTO num FROM infocontacts WHERE phone = NEW.phone;
 IF( num >0 ) THEN 
  INSERT INTO duplicated( name, surname, phone, email, profession, province) 
  VALUES (NEW.name, NEW.surname, NEW.phone, NEW.email, NEW.profession, NEW.province);

  LEAVE trig;

 END IF ;
END IF ;
END
```

The instruction "LEAVE trig;" didn't execute that is leave the trigger and don't run the insert for which was triggered!

Can someone help me?

Thanks